# What is 112328 in this publication?

Tags: citations

I would like to cite [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0926669020302442) publication in my work. This has DOI https://doi.org/10.1016/j.indcrop.2020.112328, but I am not sure what attribute the number *112328* represents. Is it just an identifier, since it is also at the end of the DOI?

I am a little confused, because for other articles published by *Elsevier,* I’ve seen headers such as:

> Modular Aspects of Medicine 31 (2010) 478–494

And here, *478–494* obviously refers to page numbers (this is from https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mam.2010.09.002). However, for the article in question, I see

> Industrial Crops & Products 148 (2020) 112328

at the same place. Surely, this journal does not have 112 328 pages?

Furthermore, when exporting to *BibTeX* on *ScienceDirect,* the contents include

```
@article{ZDUNIC2020112328,
title = {In vitro hypoglycemic, antioxidant and antineurodegenerative activity of chokeberry (Aronia melanocarpa) leaves},
journal = {Industrial Crops and Products},
volume = {148},
pages = {112328},
year = {2020},
issn = {0926-6690},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.indcrop.2020.112328},
[...]
```

which seems like *112328* refers to a page number.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- almost, thanks for pointing out my duplicate. But I suppose I’d better ask further questions at the post you linked.

Comment: So I downloaded the full issue and it appears that it is the paper number, as every paper in that issue has a very similar number.

Comment: Since then, I understand how it goes: normally (or at least from what I’ve seen), articles within journals are described by the issue and volume numbers, and then with a page range, indicating where that specific article can be found within that issue. In this case, the published journal itself has its pages numbered from 1 to n and you need to know where between 1 and n the given article is. In this case, the journal numbers its pages differently. Within the journal, the _articles_ are numbered from 1 to n. Thus, page numbers are relative to the article, not the journal. [...]

Comment: [...] The long number identifies the article within the journal.